# Boolean expression which controls the if statement in java

Tags: java, boolean-expression

```
class ee
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        boolean a;
        a=true;
        System.out.println("Answer is "+a);
        a=false;
        System.out.println("Answer is "+a);
        if(a) System.out.println("This is not executed");
        a=true;
        if(a)
        System.out.println("This is executed");
        System.out.println("10>11 is "+(10>11));
    }
}
```

Output:

Ansewr is true
Answer is false
This is executed
10>11 is false

Why it is showing "This is executed" in the third line of the output? Why "This is not executed" is not there in the output ?

Comment: You have to read some documentation about [`if` statement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/if_else_statement_in_java.htm)

Comment: I think you should use brackets with your `if`s to avoid errors in the corresponding block of statements.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look each line of the code.

```
class ee
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        boolean a;

        a=true;
        System.out.println("Answer is " + a);  // OUTPUT Answer is true

        a=false;
        System.out.println("Answer is " + a);  // OUTPUT Answer is false

        //You are basically saying that if the statement is true, do this part(Inside the curly brackets)
        // a = false here so the program will not do inside the curly brackets
        if(a)
        {
            System.out.println("This is not executed");
        }

        a=true;

        // a = true here so the program will do inside the curly brackets
        if(a)
        {
            System.out.println("This is executed");
        }

        System.out.println("10>11 is "+(10>11));
    }
}
```

I guess you know about if statements, but If you want to learn more about using `if` statements go [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because a is false in the first if, and true in the second. The statement inside the if sentence is executed only if the if's condition is true

Answer (score 0):

```
         a=false;
        System.out.println("Answer is "+a);
        if(a) System.out.println("This is not executed");
        a=true;
        if(a)
        System.out.println("This is executed");
```

If you look at your code, you are setting a to false, 
if(a) by default assumes a is true, so it does not show 
"This is not executed".
You are again setting a to true, so here it now shows
"This is executed".

Answer (score 0):

I hope it would help you, go through each comments properly,

```
boolean a;  //default value false
                a=true; //assinged 'a' to true
                System.out.println("Answer is "+a); //so it prints true here
                a=false;   //again assigned it to false
                System.out.println("Answer is "+a);  // so it prints as false here
                if(a) System.out.println("This is not executed");
        /*
        the above line means as if(a){// a is false here, then it wont go inside, HENCE IT IS NOT THERE IN OUTPUT
        System.out.println("This is not executed");
        }

        */
                a=true; // again a assigned as true
                if(a)
                System.out.println("This is executed");
    /*
        the above line means as if(a){// a is true here, then it goes inside, HENCE IT IS THERE IN OUTPUT
        System.out.println("This is executed");
        }

        */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    a=false;
    System.out.println("Answer is "+a);
    if(a) System.out.println("This is not executed");
    a=true;
    if(a)
    System.out.println("This is executed");
    System.out.println("10>11 is "+(10>11));
```

The a = false changes a to false and hence `if(a) System.out.println("This is not executed");` is not executed then passing `a=true;` makes a true and thats why `System.out.println("This is executed");` bgot executed